# How to change parent using relations in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Here is the simple example of relationship with backref and delete cascade.

```python
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('Parent.id'))
    parent = relation(
        'Parent',
        backref=backref('children', cascade='delete, delete-orphan')
    )
```

Need to reassign some children from one parent to another, then need to delete another parent, but sqlalchemy deletes children before parent removal...

```python
p1 = Session.query(Parent).get(...)
p2 = Session.query(Parent).get(...)

p1.children.extend(p2.children)
Session.delete(p2)
Session.commit()
```

Log:

```
... [worker 0] UPDATE child SET parent_id=%(parent_id)s WHERE child.id = %(child_id)s
...
... [worker 0] DELETE FROM child WHERE child.id = %(id)s
...
... [worker 0] DELETE FROM parent WHERE parent.id = %(id)s
...
... [worker 0] COMMIT
```

Need to somehow detach children from another parent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I can suggest is:

```python
p1 = Session.query(Parent).get(...)
p2 = Session.query(Parent).get(...)

for child in p2.children[:]:
    child.parent = p1

Session.delete(p2)
Session.commit()
```

Comment: But it didn't work for me (SQLAlchemy 1.1.15)! `child.parent = p1` generates this update query: `UPDATE child SET parent = 3 WHERE child.id = 45`. But the sentence `Session.delete(p2)` would generate: `UPDATE child SET parent = NULL WHERE child.id = 45`

Comment: I admit that it doesn't work, it's been six years :)

Comment: ! do you know any new solution?